# How does HTML mouseover work on apple multitouch devices?

Tags: mouse, multi-touch

I asked about this in connection with this network of websites, but it brings up a more general question that I don't know the answer to.

Is it a problem that mouse over events are not able to be invoked by apple touchscreen - especially in regard to website rollovers?

Is there a way around this?

Related:

http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/134/how-to-see-spoilers-on-touchscreen

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75656/cant-see-spoilers-on-touchscreen

Comment: The Ipad tracks your eyes and will trigger the hover event when you look at the element...oops that's a future feature ;)

Answer (score 5):

The way around this is to use a mouseover handler on a "clickable element", as Apple explain in their [Web Content Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW7):

> Mouse events are delivered in the same
>   order you'd expect in other web
>   browsers [...]. If
>   the user taps a nonclickable element,
>   no events are generated. If the user
>   taps a clickable element, events
>   arrive in this order: mouseover,
>   mousemove, mousedown, mouseup, and
>   click. The mouseout event occurs only
>   if the user taps on another clickable
>   item. Also, if the contents of the
>   page changes on the mousemove event,
>   no subsequent events in the sequence
>   are sent. This behavior allows the
>   user to tap in the new content.

Tapping once on a clickable element that has mouseover/mousemove content displays that content.  Tapping a second time does mousedown/mouseup/click.

A "clickable element" is:

> a link, form element, image map area,
>   or any other element with mousemove,
>   mousedown, mouseup, or onclick
>   handlers.

Therefore to fix the spoiler rollovers they would have to change using CSS to Javascript (i.e. use a mouseover handler on the blockquote, rather than a CSS class).

(Apple has [patent applications](http://www.slashgear.com/apple-patent-application-suggests-hover-sensing-13126307/) for detecting hovering on touch interfaces, so this could go away in the future.  However, it's unlikely that will be soon).

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a good way to do this. I've found a [bookmarklet](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20100404045906105) that lets you read alt/title text, but not much else. Enjoy.